# Dompdf UTF-8 not working but display in file

Tags: php, utf-8, dompdf

I'm trying to create pdf with special characters, but there don't display, but when i explore the file to my special characters display but not when i convert it to pdf.
I'm working on dompdf 0.8.6

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`enter code here`
```

@font-face { font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif; }

$dompdf->load_html($html, 'UTF-8');

i have already set this proposition.

Thank for ur help.

Comment: where do you 'display' the PDF ?   on some devices (iOS) , depending on the app's developer choice of Kit (Web vs UI vs PDF) , the special chars dont display properly.

Comment: Hey, how are u? i display the pdf on the web

Answer (score 0):

Either add the following code to your CSS definitions:

```
* {
    font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;
}
```

Or this code in the header of the HTML document:

```
<style>
* {
    font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

With DOM PDF 2.01 all characters were now displayed correctly. The "font-face" definition is not required.